# Ansible: How to identify which EC2 instance is the current node to extract private IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I need to update some configuration, which includes a list of all the EC2 nodes in my cluster, but also each node's configuration needs to know its own EC2 public **and** private IP address.

For the full list, I have the following:

```
- name: Gather EC2 facts on all nodes
  ec2_instance_facts:
    region: "{{ aws.region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Type": nodeType
      "tag:Name": '{{ aws.ec2.nodes.name }}'
      "instance-state-name": running
  register: ec2_facts
```

Then gather all the IPs and add them to a group:

```
- name: Gather IPs for all hosts
  add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip_address }} groups=allIpAddresses
  loop: "{{ ec2_facts.instances }}"
  when:
    - item.state.name == "running"
```

This groups variable is then used in another play and used to substitute out the values in an Ansible template:

```
- seeds: "{{ allIpAddresses[0] }},{{ allIpAddresses[1] }},{{ allIpAddresses[2] }},{{ allIpAddresses[3] }}"
```

However, I cannot seem to extract or identify which public and private IP is for the "current" host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ec2_metadata_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_metadata_facts_module.html?highlight=ec2) to gather facts in variables associated per instance. 
 Alternatively, if you want to use `ec2_instance_facts` you would do a `lookup` based on the `inventory_hostname`:

sample play:

```
- name: gather ec2 facts per instance
  hosts: my_aws_instances
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - ec2_metadata_facts:
    - name: debug
      debug: var=ansible_ec2_public_ipv4
    - name: debug
      debug: var=ansible_ec2_local_ipv4
```

Comment: Thanks, this prints out the information I am looking for.  How do I actually reference these values throughout my playbook?  I read from the docs that the values are added to `hostvars`, but I cannot seem to find them.

Comment: Got it: `set_fact: publicIp="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_ec2_public_ipv4'] }}"`